Run database upgrades manually
Is it possible to run the database upgrades (in my case, from 5.66.0 to 5.66.2) manually, i.e. just get the SQL statements and run them in the DB CLI?
I ask because both the UI upgrade and cv CLI upgrades are failing, but the former isn't giving me any information, and the latter is failing for an unrelated reason.  So now I'm in a limbo where the upgrades are sitting unapplied.

Specifically for 5.66.0 to 5.66.2 I don't see any, but in general it's difficult to manually do. You need to look in both https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/tree/master/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php and https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/tree/master/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql, and note that some run conditionally depending on specifics of your install.
Multilingual sites also run different queries. And even if it's single-lingual but not US english, you'd want strings translated.
Also you don't want to miss pre and post upgrade messages that get displayed, which are also sometimes conditional.
And then there are some general things that happen every upgrade. In particular uncustomized message templates are refreshed from the disk version in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/tree/master/xml/templates/message_templates, and messages about changes to templates. Also the db version is updated in civicrm_domain.
And then core extensions will have upgrades sometimes. It's not clear if the same issue would come up there.
For your UI issue, you could try both of:

Turn on "display backtrace" at administer - system settings - debugging.
Run the upgrade with browser dev tools open and the network tab displayed. The response of the ajax calls may have an error message displayed.

